# Adding letters to words in salat allowed?

Tags: salat

In salat when I  was doing rukoo i said subhuman rabial azeema instead of azeem on purpose.
 Is that ok?
 Does it change the meaning of the phrase?
 Do I have to repeat this prayer or is it ok?

Comment: i think the basic question here would be are you an Arabic native speaker? If yes then you would know the main and grief difference and would probably have to repent and repeat your prayer. If not then at least you'll have to repent!

Answer (score 1):

`azeema` is the feminine name for `azeem`.

It is forbidden by many scholars to give female assignments to Allah, as he gave himself male assignments in the Quran when referring to himself. Examples like:

- Alanajim:45
- Alanam:101
- Alanam:73
- Rome:27
- Alzaorph:84

Similar question in [Arabic](http://islamqa.info/ar/98689).

Because you didn't know I wouldn't say you have to repeat the Prayers, since Allah knows the intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask any wish you want in prayer. But you should not change the phrases what Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) have taught us. It is uniform for all muslims.